# Dialogflow console consistently shows a blank screen

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I've been unable to access the Dialogflow console. I've tried logging out and logging back in, clearing site data, using different browsers and incognito mode. I even gave myself Dialogflow admin permissions through Google Cloud Console's IAM.

I've submitted a support request, but waiting on a response. Other folks have asked similar questions on stackoverflow without any response so far. I hope someone can share how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to reset your account as indicated in this [similar issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/153042511#comment2) from the Public Issue Tracker, specifically follow the steps from comment#2.

If the issue persist, you will need to wait the response from support.

Answer (score 0):

While Isaac's answer here is valid and something that was suggested by the support team as well, the reason turned out to be a change in my email address. The fix was done by Dialogflow's team behind the scenes.

If anyone else faces an issue logging into Dialogflow and have made any change to their email address (including domain) recently, that would be something you would want to convey to Dialogflow's support upfront.